# How could people on our world recognize time travelers if they are trying to hide their identity?

Tags: society, humans, time-travel, social-norms

Regarding time travel to our timeline, many have assumed that time travelers would reveal themselves as such, most notably Stephen Hawking's party for time travelers that he announced after the fact. Not surprisingly, no one showed up. Hawking stated this as proof that time travel is not possible, ignoring the other possibility that it could become known as the most boring party of all time, not worth traveling back decades or centuries to attend. (Would you fly to to another continent to attend such a party? Were there food and drinks?) But I digress. If on the other hand, time travelers had other plausible reasons not to reveal themselves, that have been explored in some depth on this site, how could they be spotted? This seems to have some parallels to exposing terrorists, with them having the added advantage that most of society does not believe it's possible (similar to alien visitation). What would the clues be? Or combination of clues. What would visitors from another timeline get wrong in their preparation or execution that would get them noticed in ours? Would it be easier for them to blend in our era verses another one? How big of a blunder on their part would it have to be get noticed by the government or scientists?

I hope this rewriting meets the protocol of this site.

Comment: It's impossible that people just find out "wow this guy is clearly from the futur". It is the last plausible cause to a weird comportment.
Unless they know that their is some time travelers around nobody will find out. They will think they are ignorant, dumb or crazy but not

Comment: Or foreign. People from far enough away are often strange.

Comment: Or domestic. People in my town are often strange.

Comment: Elon Musk is clearly a traveler from the future, sent back to save Earth.  Tesla sadly suffered from time-anomoly dementia.  Also, there are rumors that Steve Jobs didn't die; he just went home.

Comment: There are lots of things that are almost impossible for a time traveller to get right, Nex Terren has made a good list, but keep in mind that most likely even if someone did all of these things, people will always assume something that isn't time travel to explain the inconsistencies. If we're in medieval times the time traveller would probably be accused of being a witch, or mad, depending on what they do wrong, earlier they'd be magicians/prophets or prodigies (or just mad again). In recent times there'd be some conspiracy theories about time travellers but few persons would believe them.

Comment: Apart from being highly depend on each and everyone's opinion (amplified by a lack of details), it is about a story, not a world-building, and as such it is off-topic. Please check the [tour] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: I disagree about the reason given for putting this question on hold. It isn't about a specific story or how its characters act or react. It is asking what would give away time travellers in our contemporary world. The question may be too broadly worded or perhaps asked infelicitatiously enough, but it isn't story based. The world it is building is the contemporary world plus time travellers. Yes I read the post on 'Story based' before posting this comment. The OP is new here, be nice. And helpful.

Comment: I wish I could have answered this: Language. Unless they spend tons of time on linguistic differences, a time traveller would show itself by talking with a totally different set of words. Imagine yourself going back to the 19th century britain

Comment: Ok, that answer is given before the question is closed, yay.

Answer (score 3):

**Accent, Dialect**

Try to get a German, or Spanish, or Italian accent just right... and then go talk to a native speaker. Shoot, try to get a Southern, Boston, or Californian accent right and see if a native can tell. They most likely will be able to, and we're in the same time.

**Verbal expressions**

Seriously, the medieval expressions you think you know? Span normally over several hundred years. If we use expressions dated by even 10 years we get odd looks. How about expressions dating 50 years? Time travelers need to know the EXACT expressions.

**Polite mannerisms**

Similar to the previous one. Do you bow right? The right depth? What do you do with your hands while bowing? Is the peace sign a thing currently? Does it actually mean something different in this culture? Do we hold doors open for people?

**Assumptions about technology**

Having lived through the 90s I can only imagine how awkward it would be to try to go back and remember how every nuance worked. How does a dial-up modem work again? And I honestly don't remember the nuances about long distant calling and the alternatives, being a child at the time. I can only imagine trying to struggle through simple tasks like this in the 1950s.

**Forgetting the order of events**

Quick, did Enron file for bankruptcy before or after 9/11? How about when did California's rolling blackouts begin that year? Were the DC snipers before or after these things? When did the No Child Left Behind act become law? That was before 9/11... or was it?

Now imagine accidentally recalling an event... before it happened.

**Clothing**

So you're a medieval enthusiast. Congratulations! Now, do you *really* think you could pull off 1670s century Spanish nobility clothing accurately? Shoot, if you're an adult, try to go and understand modern high school fashion; you'll find it fairly challenging I imagine.

Comment: These things may give away that someone isn't from around here or even that they are just a bit ignorant relative to someone who knows them - it would never make them suspect you're from the future!

Comment: @colmde Well, trying to use a PC in the 90s as a touch screen, or wondering why devices in the 80s aren't wireless might, but I feel "predicting events before they happens" pretty safely puts you in the "time traveler" slot.

Comment: The assumptions about technology and forgetting the order of events are really good points - even so it might take a few trip-ups to get found out, but they're pretty good proofs.  Some of the others are likely to get waved off as being ignorant, or from a different culture - easy to say they're not from here, harder to rule out everywhere else they might have been from *and* how they would have acted if they were.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial knowledge such as recent sports scores, along with manners and slang have all been used as "tells" in Time Travel fiction.  I vaguely remember one short story where a man's failure to adjust his stiff all-cotton pants before sitting down revealed that he came from a later decade which had stretch fabrics.

Personally, I find these methods questionable simply because of how complex our society is and has been for hundreds of years.  There are always individuals who are ignorant of one custom or another.  There are technophilles who know nothing of sports and technophobes who don't really understand what the internet is.  In any given day, I encounter dozens of people and most of them don't act exactly as our mainstream culture expects.  They all have odd tells and mannerisms, but I am pretty sure that none of them are travelers from a distant age.

I think the easiest way to reveal a time traveler is through their possessions.  First of all, they will have very limited identification.  False IDs are no where near as easy to acquire as fiction would suggest.  You might be able to get something that can fool a bouncer at a bar, but getting a drivers license which has your picture on it and which can pass a police officer's radioed-in check... no, that is not easily available.

In addition to missing or incomplete identification, travelers may possess current day items and clothing, taken from museums in their home time.  These articles will show signs of extreme aging, despite being appropriate for the year and country which they are visiting.  A IPhone-6s in a white plastic protector which has yellowed and turned brittle with age.  Some 2015 World-Series regalia which is faded and thread-bare from years of use.

Comment: Fake IDs are trivial for a time traveler to get. All he has to do is travel back in time to 60s or 70s and plant a birth certificate, then in present time apply for a passport.

Comment: @ventsyv, Great Idea.  There could even be teams of time travelers who work together to generate an identity.  A pregnant couple who travels back to the 60's to delivery a child, thus securing a birth certificate.  (Not sure where the parents get their identities from, but lets table that for now)  Then an adult and teenager pair who arrive in the late 70's to acquire a drivers license.  Incrementally older solo travelers who renew the license and pay taxes every year or so.  Very plausible.  I will use that in one of my stories.  Thanks!

Comment: What a minute! A pregnant couple travels back to the 1960's! What are you thinking? Compare medical standards between now and then, let alone what obstetric medicine will be like in a future where time travel is a working technology. It might be easier to create fake documents and plant them in the old systems, say, at night when no-one's around. Yes organisations building truly false backgrounds and documents for time travellers is a golden idea.

Comment: @a4android, good points.  No pregnant couple.  Too dangerous for the mother to be!  So we get the first birth certificate for a late-20th century time traveller by bribing a file clerk in the 40's.  Then a time traveler with that birth certificate goes back to the 60's and gets a job in the birth certificate filing department of a hospital.  No birth certificates for travellers to the 80's and later are easy to acquire. Use one of them to put a traveller in the records departments of a highschool, a college and the DMV.  Instant identities for everyone!

Comment: @HenryTaylor I prefer burglary to bribery. Slipping a copy of  a fake 40s birth into the record in the 50s would go unnoticed. Bribing officials requires good local cultural knowledge. Nocturnal visits and swapping all relevant records with 'new' versions is much safer and simpler. You have all the time in the world to make the right changes with time travel. Working in Records would be absolute Hell for someone from the future. Also taking years to do. One night's work by burglary after careful observation and production of the fakes.

Comment: @a4android, All solid points.  But a low rank traveller who is spending a miserable year as a clerk to earn their way into a better assignment, now that is a a relatable character.  Time Travellers are too powerful to make good POV characters. A protagonist needs some weaknesses to help the reader care about them.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I remembered that identity theft and creating false identities was easier in the past,at least, up until the 1980s when stringent checks were introduced. Bank accounts, drivers' licences etc could be obtained without proof of identity. Travellers use that to progressively build fake identities over time. A traveller in today's world could have a comprehensive family history created lay by layer.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Don't you want to rise to the challenge of writing powerful characters and making them relatable. Readers don't relate to characters because of their flaws. They want the characters to overcome obstacles to achieve their goal (obstacles can include their flaws) whether they succed or not.

Comment: @a4android, I really have to thank you for all this commentary.  I'm starting to layout a story line which starts in the identity-acquisition department of a time-travel agency.  I especially like what you said 5 hours ago about less-stringent regulations pre-1980's.  As for your challenge, I will have to pass.  Powerful non-pov characters tend to vector downward in my world, while weaker pov characters rise.  That is a general trend in my writing that I recognized years ago and don't want to change.  It works for me.

Comment: @HenryTaylor if it works for you, just keep doing it. RE identity acquisition, try Frederick Forsyth's THE DAY OF THE JACKAL. It shows how an assassin operating in France creates false identities. Some of which would be true elsewhere in mid-20th century. Glad I was of some small help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend greed as the cause, one of the time travelers just couldn't help but use that quantum screwdriver or use that important information to make enough money to buy a secret golden fortress.

Things like that would be solutions but if you want them all to try very hard to fit in and be discovered I'd say the group's reaction to important events would be the only clear indication, and even then you need someone who calls them out to be a master lie detector.